# Replacing sync callbacks with Kotlin sequence

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the below sample, a callback is invoked many times until input is consumed. How do I make this into a `Sequence` or `Flow` suitable for on-the-fly consumption? I see many (seriously, loads - does no one *read* SO) similar coroutine questions for *one-shot* callbacks resolved using `suspendCoroutine` but I cannot see how to apply that here. I'm sure there's something involving a `Channel()` that I could not make work ...

Any pointers appreciated!

```kotlin
    fun String.inputStream(): InputStream = object {}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream(this)

    fun main() {
        val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader("/file.txt".inputStream()))
        input.mark(1000)
        readeR(input, Consumer { println(it) } ) // Synchronous call
        input.reset()
        sequenceR(input).forEach { println(it) } // Async-sequence
    }

    // This is a mockup of existing (Java) code, cannot change this method
    fun readeR(reader: BufferedReader, handleR: Consumer<String>) {
        do {
            val line = reader.readLine()
            if (line != null && line.startsWith("R")) handleR.accept(line)
        } while (line != null)
    }

    // TODO
    fun sequenceR(r: BufferedReader) = sequence {
        readeR(r, Consumer { yield(it) }) // <<< Q1 How to build sequence from the callbacks
        yield(null) // <<< Q2 How to close the sequence?
    }.constrainOnce()
```

Comment: You need a separate thread for the `readeR` invocation, that's the easy part. You also need a concurrency primitive that is blocking on the sending side, but suspending on the receiving side. This is the tricky part.

Comment: This is what I've been trying with `channel.sendBlocking(it)` but the specifics escape me.

Comment: Why don't you show the results of your attempt. I guess the `handleR` will contain that `sendBlocking` line.

Comment: On the receiving side you must use a `Flow` and not a `Sequence`. In fact, try packaging everything into a `channelFlow` (both the producing and the consuming code).

Answer (score 3):

Huge thanks (but no points!) to @marko-topolnik for knowledge of [`channelFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html). I *knew* there would an elegant solution out there

```kotlin
    fun main() {
        val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader("/file.txt".inputStream()))
        runBlocking {
            flowR(reader).collect { println(it) } // Async-supplied iterator
        }
    }

    fun flowR(r: BufferedReader): Flow<String> = channelFlow {
        readeR(r, Consumer<String> { sendBlocking(it) })
    }
```

Comment: Very nice solution!